# Expressão regular para reordenar string

Tags: php, string, regex, preg-replace

Tenho o resultado de uma *query* com vários `joins`, e em uma linha eu tenho a concatenação de 2 grupos. A linha me retorna uma *string* como: `1,4|a1,b4`.

O que eu preciso é reagrupar *ID e Valor* da seguinte forma: `array( 1 => a1 , 4 => b4 )`, ou de forma similar, mas sem entulhar com uso de `explode` e recombinar o array.

Pensei em usar `preg_replace`, mas não consegui uma regra funcional.

Comment: Os números podem ter quantos dígitos? Iniciam em um ou zero? Pode ocorrer zero no início? a1 e b4 são valores aleatórios ou sempre vai ser a, b, c etc. seguidos dos mesmos números que ocorreram anteriormente?

Comment: @Pablo, sem ocorrências de zeros e valores aleatórios.

Comment: Sugeriria dar uma olhada no código fonte que implementa RegEx, para ter uma idéia da complexidade. "Entulhar com uso de explode e recombinar o array" é fichinha perto disso. Agora, se no mesmo source você for processar a mesma RegEx um número bem alto de vezes, talvez a pré-compilação dela traga alguma vantagem.

Comment: @Bacco, pois é. Com explode dá pra fazer e recombinar os arrays, mas fica "feio". Essa repetição de função não me agrada muito.

Comment: @PapaCharlie entendo, você está pensando na estética do código, e não no processamento. Acho válido você usar o estilo que dê menos manutenção e melhor facilidade de leitura para você (e isso é realmente bem pessoal). Eu muitas vezes opto pela legibilidade também, em partes do código que não afetam significativamente a performance. Só achei interessante comentar, pois muita gente não faz idéia de como RegEx é complexo "sob o capô".

Comment: Infelizmente nem cheguei a tentar com `regex`, mas tenho uma solução meio, digamos trabalhada.

Comment: Desfiz a string de entrada, e reagrupei os membros um à um, mas no caso, vai depender de ti - _"mas sem entulhar com uso de explode e recombinar o array"_- para aceitar a solução que proponho.

Comment: @Bacco, Sei dos 'cuidados' do uso com as ERs, mas no caso veio a dúvida se compensa uma ER ou 3 explodes + reorganização do array. Com explode ja esta feito e funcionando, só queria 'uma linha' mais pratica :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie é, precisei de duas linha pra fazer a versão entulhada, mas ainda desconfio que só com o RegEx de qualquer forma nao vai ser simples também. Vamos ver o que aparece de alternativa, de repente sai alguma coisa engenhosa.

Comment: @Bacco acho que uma ER pra isso vai ter um monte de condição diabólica rs. Vou seguir a navalha de occam por enquanto...

Comment: @PapaCharlie vou postar a versão explode, e mais uma alternativa sem RegEx mais como repositório para outros usuários mesmo. De qualquer forma, vamos esperar por soluções RegEx

Comment: @Bacco Não entendi a parte do "fichinha perto disso". Uma expressão regular compilada é O(n). Isso é bastante rápido.

Comment: @Pablo O(n) é medida de complexidade, e não velocidade. `sleep( 10000 )` é O(n) também. E como você bem disse, _depois de compilada_ ela é bem rápida mesmo, por isso eu disse que se for usar várias vezes no mesmo source pode ter alguma vantagem. Só que lembre-se que em PHP ela vai ser compilada novamente a cada acesso.

Comment: @Pablo complementando o que o Bacco disse, tem O(N) que leva nanosegundos e tem O(N) que leva anos. Depende do valor de N e do tempo necessário para processar cada item. Em termos de performance, qualquer solução aí será rápida.

Comment: @Bacco O mesmo vale para o código postado na resposta. Todos serão compilados todas as vezes. E medida de complexidade serve justamente para analisar a velocidade. Se você conhece uma medida mais adequada para analisar algoritmos sem executá-los (que é tudo o que o AP parece disposto a fazer), por favor, me apresente.

Comment: @Pablo não esqueça que chamar uma função em PHP é chamar todo o código que roda por trás dela. Não adianta querer apenas aplicar o Big-O nessa camada e achar que fez a lição de casa. Outra coisa, sobre o "medida de complexidade serve para analisar velocidade", seria legal rever um pouco melhor a teoria, pois não é esse o conceito, nem simples assim. Espero que não entenda como crítica, mas sim como um incentivo a repensar na coisa toda. Talvez até reler os comments para separar o que foi dito de fato, do que você entendeu do que foi dito. Quanto à performance, nao parece ser o foco da questão.

Comment: @Bacco Eu estou sempre disposto a aprender. Por isso estou te perguntando se você conhece uma melhor forma de estimar o desempenho de forma analítica sem apelar para complexidade assintótica. Concordo com você com a questão das chamadas de funções, mas eu não vejo como você escapa de chamadas de funções usando o método de explode. Você está descartando a minha análise intuitiva do problema simplesmente dizendo que não é bem assim, mas eu gostaria de saber como é, então.

Comment: @Pablo não estou descartando, mas sim questionando o método aplicado. Compare o fluxo de trabalho de um explode e da compilação de um regex, não precisaria nem de Big-O para ver que o problema é diferente. De qualquer forma, melhor do que opinião seria você olhar os fontes do PHP e das libs envolvidas. De repente você descobre alguma coisa interessante. Se descobrir que RegEx não é tão complexo assim, comente aqui. Estou aberto a aprender também. O que não tou muito afim é ficar debatendo aqui o assunto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Versão alternativa, sem RegEx

Não como resposta ao problema principal, mas como alternativa para outros usuários que tenham necessidade de fazer *parse* de strings neste formato, segue uma solução sem RegEx:

```
$in   = '1,4|a1,b4';

$pair = explode('|',$in);
$out  = array_combine(explode(',',$pair[0]),explode(',',$pair[1]));
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8oRXYx)**.

Conforme postado pelo [bfavaretto ♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74) nos *comments*, segue uma alternativa que reconstrói os dados em uma linha só:

```
$s='1,4|a1,b4';
$o=call_user_func_array("array_combine", array_chunk(str_word_count($s,1,'1234567890'),2));
print_r( $o );
```

Repostei esta alterativa por ter achado interessante como uma vitrine de algumas funções menos conhecidas do PHP. Para uso normal, o `explode` vai direto ao ponto.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rT7Ir8)**.

Comment: Se alguém quiser arriscar, segue uma [gambi de uma linha](http://ideone.com/rT7Ir8).

Answer (score 2):

> *sem entulhar com uso de explode e recombinar o array*

Sinto dizer, mas com regex não fica mais simples. Na verdade, eu diria que fica até mais "entulhado", e não tem como escapar de recombinar o array.

Eu recomendo que continue usando `explode`, como sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99393/112052). Mas só para mostrar como não ficaria mais simples:

```php
// testando com mais chaves e valores
$in = '1,4,6,9|a1,b4,c6,d9';
if (preg_match_all('/[^|,]+/', $in, $matches)) {
    $len = count($matches[0]) / 2;
    $out = array_combine(array_slice($matches[0], 0, $len), array_slice($matches[0], $len));
    print_r($out);
}
```

Ou seja, estou pegando uma ou mais ocorrências (`+`) de [qualquer coisa que **não** seja](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `|` nem vírgula (`[^|,]`). O problema é que esta regex não verifica o formato e simplesmente aceita qualquer coisa que esteja entre as vírgulas.

Com isso, o array `$matches` contém um único array que tem todas as chaves e valores. Se eu fizesse `print_r($matches);`, o resultado seria:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 9
            [4] => a1
            [5] => b4
            [6] => c6
            [7] => d9
        )

)
```

Então eu preciso recombinar este array: a primeira metade dos elementos são as chaves, e a segunda metade são os respectivos valores. É isso que o `array_combine` acima está fazendo. O resultado final é:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => a1
    [4] => b4
    [6] => c6
    [9] => d9
)
```

Um problema é que a regex não verifica o formato, pois poderia ter vários `|` na string separando os campos (e nenhuma vírgula), ou qualquer outra combinação. Já a solução com `explode` "garante" pelo menos que deve ter um `|` separando os campos.

Claro que se as entradas são controladas e você tem certeza que o formato está sempre correto, não tem tanto problema assim. Mas fica a ressalva.

---

Mas se quiser que a regex seja mais "rígida" e só aceite o formato indicado, teria que ser algo como:

```php
if (preg_match_all('/(?<=^|,)\d+|(?<=[|,])[a-z]\d/', $in, $matches)) {
    // resto do código é igual
}
```

Estou assumindo que as chaves são sempre dígitos (`\d+`: um ou mais dígitos) e os valores são sempre uma letra seguida de um dígito (`[a-z]\d`). Se não for, basta ajustar (por exemplo, se forem várias letras seguidas de vários dígitos, troque para `[a-z]+\d+`).

Também uso [*lookbehinds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que verificam se algo ocorre antes de determinado trecho. No caso, antes dos números tem o *lookbehind* `(?<=^|,)`, que verifica se antes deles tem o início da string (`^`) ou uma vírgula. Ou seja, ele pega os números que estão no início (antes do `|`). E antes dos valores (`a1`, `b2`, etc) tem o *lookbehind* `(?<=[|,])`, que verifica se antes tem um `|` ou uma vírgula.

O array de *matches* terá o mesmo formato do código anterior, com todas as chaves e em seguida todos os valores.

Claro, esta é uma opção caso queira forçar uma verificação um pouco mais rígida. Mas se você "sabe" que o formato da string de entrada sempre é válido, bastaria pegar tudo que está entre as vírgulas (e aí, na minha opinião, continua sendo melhor usar `explode`).

Outra alternativa é usar grupos de captura para as chaves e valores:

```php
if (preg_match_all('/(?<=^|,)(\d+)|(?<=[|,])([a-z]\d)/', $in, $matches)) {
    $out = array_combine(array_filter($matches[1]), array_filter($matches[2]));
    print_r($out);
}
```

Agora as chaves e valores estão entre parênteses, o que cria grupos de captura. No caso, as chaves estarão em `$matches[1]` e os respectivos valores em `$matches[2]`. Mas como em cada *match* somente um deles é preenchido, esses arrays possuem várias strings vazias (faça um `print_r($matches)` para conferir), por isso a necessidade de usar `array_filter` para eliminá-los.

---

Enfim, embora seja possível, será que ficou "melhor"? Compare com a solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99393/112052), que na minha opinião ficou melhor em vários aspectos: não só mais curto (que nem deveria ser o critério principal) como também - na minha opinião - mais claro, simples e fácil de entender e manter, sem contar que *provavelmente* é mais eficiente (esses sim, deveriam ser os principais critérios).

Claro, eu não testei o desempenho, mas minha suspeita é que `explode` seja mais eficiente sim, pois regex esconde uma complexidade enorme por trás (como o fato de [precisar ser compilada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486263/112052), fora toda a estrutura por trás da *engine*, [veja aqui](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/pcre/pcre2lib) como não é nada simples). [Compare com o `explode`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.10/ext/standard/string.c#L1024) para ver como é mais simples.

Lembre-se que [código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052) (e pior que nesse caso nem ficou menor).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que essa expressão captura o que você deseja. Basta ajeitar os grupos de captura para extrair os dados que você quer.

```
([1-9][0-9]*,)*[1-9][0-9]*\|[a-z]*(,[a-z]+)*
```

Um detalhe importante é que não existe forma, usando expressão regular, de garantir que o lado esquerdo tem a mesma quantidade de itens que o lado direito. Isso seria trabalho para, no mínimo, uma *Gramática Livre de Contexto*.